# OCAException while trying to update ProductPO custom attribute

Tags: exception, intershop

We are getting following exception when trying to update custom attribute on ProductPO with UpdateCustomAttribute pipelet:

```
Caused by: com.intershop.beehive.orm.capi.common.OCAException: Could not UPDATE object: com.intershop.beehive.xcs.internal.product.ProductPO ...
```

Does anyone know why is that? Maybe because we hold ProductPO object which we try to update in session?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there any code that updates either product or product_av asynchronously when processing the request? Are you using implicit transaction handling on the pipelet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common exception when you have multiple request/process updating the same object.
See [intershop ORMException could not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580096/intershop-ormexception-could-not-update-refresh-ormobject/45605135) that explains this concept well.

Holding the ProductPO in the session is a very bad idea. Intershop will not look through the session objects to sync product data. Better idea is to store the UUID and lookup the product each time you update it. UUID because with that you will hit the ORM cache and not the DB every time.

Comment: Thanks, will try that way.