# OCAException while updating Product quantity (custom attribute)

Tags: java, intershop

We have multiple application servers, and now and then our orders are failing with OCAException.

The problem is that updating product quantity (custom attribute) from external system is part of our order workflow and this exception occurs sometimes, not always.

I already saw discussion here [intershop ORMException could not update - refresh ORMObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580096/intershop-ormexception-could-not-update-refresh-ormobject/45605135#answer-45605135), so I know the issue here - updating object in other thread and/or application server. But I can't understand why this exception occurs even in our test instances when Update Quantity job is running for example in 6 AM when there is nothing else happening - no other job is running, no user activity?

The job itself lasts for about 7 seconds and it is executed in one transaction pipelet which iterates over WS response objects, then gets productBO from repository by SKU, updates Quantity custom attribute and sets product offline or online based on it.

Why is this happening and how to avoid/fix it?

```
[2018-12-01 06:55:09.962 +0100] [JobExecutor60679518] [Job:ESBImportQuantity] [Req:X5sK_SlynRsAAAFndZuVlWhV] ERROR com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.job.JobExecutor  - Job 'ESBImportQuantity' pipeline finished with exception! com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineCallStackException: com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: Exception occurred while executing pipelet 'ESBUpdateProductQuantity'.
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:1038)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:641)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:484)
    at com.intershop.beehive.pipeline.internal.PipelineEngineImpl.executePipeline(PipelineEngineImpl.java:97)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:421)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:250)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.job.JobExecutor.runJob(JobExecutor.java:399)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.job.JobExecutor.processTask(JobExecutor.java:171)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.environment.Worker.run(Worker.java:270)
Caused by: com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: Exception occurred while executing pipelet 'ESBUpdateProductQuantity'.
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipeletNode.executeNode(PipeletNode.java:381)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executeNode(Pipeline.java:1098)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:926)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: com.intershop.beehive.orm.capi.common.OCAException: Could not UPDATE object: com.intershop.beehive.xcs.internal.product.ProductPO
```

The same exception occurs when system job "ProcessProductNotification-TriggerNotificationFromJob" runs and tries to update DomainPO object:

```
[2018-12-03 01:24:59.159 +0100] ERROR lvpislive1.vipnet.hr ES1 appserver1 [] [] com.intershop.beehive.core.pipelet.pipeline.ExecutePipeline [] [Unknown] [hwUK_SlyrrEAAAFlp31ujvES] [rSEK85q4Zc8AAAFn9y.Wg3F0] "JobExecutor658081066" ISH-CORE-2490: Synchronous called pipeline 'ProcessProductNotification-TriggerNotificationFromJob' of application 'a1-shop@A1-Shop-Site (app=a1.Web)' has finished with exception:  com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineCallStackException: com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: Exception occurred while executing pipelet 'UpdateSyncRecord'.
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:1038)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:641)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:484)
at com.intershop.beehive.pipeline.internal.PipelineEngineImpl.executePipeline(PipelineEngineImpl.java:97)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:421)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:250)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.pipelet.pipeline.ExecutePipeline.execute(ExecutePipeline.java:175)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipeletNode.executeNode(PipeletNode.java:346)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executeNode(Pipeline.java:1098)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:926)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:641)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:484)
at com.intershop.beehive.pipeline.internal.PipelineEngineImpl.executePipeline(PipelineEngineImpl.java:97)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:421)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:250)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.job.JobExecutor.runJob(JobExecutor.java:399)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.job.JobExecutor.processTask(JobExecutor.java:171)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.environment.Worker.run(Worker.java:270)
Caused by: com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: Exception occurred while executing pipelet 'UpdateSyncRecord'.
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipeletNode.executeNode(PipeletNode.java:381)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executeNode(Pipeline.java:1098)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:926)
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: com.intershop.beehive.orm.capi.common.OCAException: Could not UPDATE object: com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.domain.DomainPO[com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.state.ObjectState@65beb960[typeCode=1, status=1, parentSiteID=null, siteID=j5UK_SlytKwAAAFlTuJujvEU, entryMask=0, pageCachingAllowedFlag=false, staticContentMaxAge=null, pageCacheID=null, staticContentCacheID=null, profileID=null, serverGroup=null, businessModel=null, defaultApplicationID=null, UUID=aPIK_Sly.tEAAAFlWeJujvEU, domainID=aPIK_Sly.tEAAAFlWeJujvEU, oca=2492]]
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineRequest.commitTransaction(PipelineRequest.java:327)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipeletNode.executeNode(PipeletNode.java:374)
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.intershop.beehive.orm.capi.common.OCAException: Could not UPDATE object: com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.domain.DomainPO[com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.state.ObjectState@65beb960[typeCode=1, status=1, parentSiteID=null, siteID=j5UK_SlytKwAAAFlTuJujvEU, entryMask=0, pageCachingAllowedFlag=false, staticContentMaxAge=null, pageCacheID=null, staticContentCacheID=null, profileID=null, serverGroup=null, businessModel=null, defaultApplicationID=null, UUID=aPIK_Sly.tEAAAFlWeJujvEU, domainID=aPIK_Sly.tEAAAFlWeJujvEU, oca=2492]]
at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.query.SQLManagerImpl.createDMLStatement(SQLManagerImpl.java:375)
at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.query.SQLManagerImpl.createUpdateStatement(SQLManagerImpl.java:252)
at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.query.QueryManagerImpl.executeDMLStatement(QueryManagerImpl.java:112)
at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.query.QueryManagerImpl.executeUpdateQuery(QueryManagerImpl.java:76)
at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.state.StateManagerImpl.updateObjectState(StateManagerImpl.java:60)
at com.intershop.beehive.orm.capi.common.ORMObject.prepareState(ORMObject.java:1868)
at com.intershop.beehive.orm.capi.common.ORMObject.transactionPrepared(ORMObject.java:1807)
at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.transaction.TransactionImpl.prepareTransaction(TransactionImpl.java:709)
at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:307)
at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineRequest.commitTransaction(PipelineRequest.java:314)
... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is your cache sync messaging working? The local server state does not match the database state and can cause this kind of errors. You need to trace all modifications of the object to trace the issue with parallel updates otherwise. What do you update on your domain object. Seems to be request updates with  'oca=2492'.

Comment: How to check if cache sync messaging working? We do not modify domain object, this is system job ProcessProductNotification that updates domain object every time it is executed.

Comment: You may enable debug logging for the class 'com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationManagerImpl'. You see debug log entries like 'Received synchronization event XXX from VMID YYY.' for ORM cache sync events. The VMID (ID for each VM/appserver) should be different from time to time.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that cache sync is working: "DEBUG ES1 appserver0 [] [] com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationManagerImpl [] [] [] [] "MulticastReceiverThread 1464311172" Received synchronization event 2 from VMID 131e47580744f893:-2d16d2c9:1677c8bb3a2:-8000."

Comment: So best option is to enable ORM logging (debug or trace), set the debug log file size to 500-1000MB (depends on traffic) and check for parallel changes of the object before the exception. 1. Enable logging; 2. wait for exception; 3. Stop logging; 4. filter all log lines with the object key (UUID?) of the logfile with the exception; 5. cross check the requests for the parallel changes based on the request ID with the WA request log and the job log (if job is involved)